# How to position a button at the bottom of a bounding rectangle in canvas

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

I'm working on positioning a button on top of my canvas but a little lower than my bounding rectangle that I've drawn on my canvas, I have the variable `bboxX`, `bboxY`, `bboxWidth`, `bboxHeight` which is the attributes of the bounding rectangle in my canvas. I'm using `getBoundingClientRect()` to get the offset of the canvas and adding it to the coordinate of the bounding box in the canvas but the button position isn't right. How can I position the button the way I want?

This is what I'm trying to achieve:

[image]

```js
const video = <HTMLVideoElement> document.getElementById("vid");

const canvas = <HTMLCanvasElement> document.getElementById("canvas");

const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

ctx.drawImage(this.video, 0, 0, canvas.width,canvas.height);

ctx.strokeStyle = "#00FFFF";
ctx.lineWidth = 2;
ctx.strokeRect(bboxX, bboxY, bboxWidth, bboxHeight);

let rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();

let positionX = (bboxX + rect.left).toString() + "px";
let positionY = (bboxY + rect.top).toString() + "px";

document.getElementById("button").style.visibility = "visible";
document.getElementById("button").style.top = positionY;
document.getElementById("button").style.left = positionX;
```

```css
canvas{
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 10;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

#button{
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 15;
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <button id="button">Show</button>
    <video hidden id="vid" width="300" height="300"></video>
    <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use a relative position...
Not clear why you are using the `canvas.getBoundingClientRect` in your placement of the button you need to align with the rectangle you draw not the entire canvas.

See code below:

```js
const canvas =  document.getElementById("canvas");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
let bboxX = 20
let bboxY = 10
let bboxWidth = 100
let bboxHeight = 60

ctx.lineWidth = 2;
ctx.strokeRect(bboxX, bboxY, bboxWidth, bboxHeight);

let rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
let positionX = (bboxX + bboxWidth/2 -25).toString() + "px";

const button = document.getElementById("button")
button.style.visibility = "visible";
button.style.left = positionX;
```

```css
#button{
    visibility: hidden;
    position: relative;
    width:50px;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <canvas id="canvas" width="300" height="80"></canvas>
    <br>
    <button id="button" >Show</button>    
 </div>
```

The key in that code is:
`let positionX = (bboxX + bboxWidth/2 -25)`
that center aligns the button with the rectange.

`bboxX + bboxWidth/2` is the center of the rectange,
then we subtract `-25` half of the button width.